# Pergunta excluída aparecendo nos testes da fila de Análise

Tags: bug, status-intencional, filas-de-análise

Estava analisando a fila de análise de "Votos para Fechar" hoje, e me deparei com a seguinte pergunta:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Até aí tudo bem, é apenas mais um teste normal e que já "estamos" acostumado.

O problema, é que ao acessar a pergunta eu percebi que a pergunta **está excluída** (pelo menos para quem não tem 10k de reputação).

Visto que ela não pode ser visto pelo link original, é certo aparecer como testes?

[Link original da pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136341/como-funcionam-os-aplicativos-de-m%C3%BAsica-offline)

Comment: relacionado http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/auditoria-nas-filas-de-an%c3%a1lise

Answer (score 5):

Não é um BUG, isso ocorre no SOen também, assim como deve ocorrer em outros sites da SE, o "teste" aplicado usa fontes verdadeiras (como perguntas abandonadas que foram excluídas automaticamente) pra testar a sua atenção, na lógica ali provavelmente ele pediu pra aprovar uma edição ou reabertura, isso ocorre pra forçar as pessoas a criarem o interesse de analisar o melhor possível a pergunta.

Se notar alguns testes de perguntas sobre edição mesclam conteúdo que parece real, mas ao ler não tem sentido algum, isso porque o sistema pega conteúdo de outra(s) perguntas para tentar fazer parecer ter algum sentido, quem prestar atenção vai notar que ou a edição é um "vandalismo" ou um "teste".

Observe também que a edição apresenta o perfil de uma pessoa que editou a pergunta, mas as vezes essa pessoa nunca acessou determinada pergunta, ou a conta deste usuário não tem atividades (geralmente aqueles que se cadastram mas não voltam).

Tudo isso é pra **tentar simular** uma situação e testar se estamos prestando realmente atenção.

Comment: Isso tudo eu considero certo. Exceto o fato de os testes usarem perguntas que realmente existem, mas foram excluídas. Imagine que essa pergunta fosse um ofensiva, spam ou outras situações?

Comment: @Randrade eu não sei se houve incidentes com isto, acredito que dependendo da sinalização a pergunta não entra nesta situação, se houver algum problema do genero, procure um moderador e notifique, é provavel que ele consiga adicionar a uma lista de exceção, ou mudar/adicionar o tipo de flag como SPAM, assim não aparecerá na fila (não tenho certeza), outra situação que pode fazer é relatar como BUG http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=análise%20bug

Comment: Minha dúvida seria algo como isso. A pergunta já está com essas tag's. Achei que não seria necessário criar outra. Se for bug's os moderadores verão. Se não, acho que responderão também.

Comment: @Randrade eu quis dizer se ocorrer um incidente de perguntas ofensivas, esse não é o caso, o problema desta é o uso das perguntas deletadas ;)

Comment: O único problema que vejo é esse. Não sei se perguntas excluídas (até respostas) possuem uma classificação, ou se estão utilizando algo do tipo. Mostrar perguntas "fictícias" ou autores diferentes eu acho normal. Agora, mostrar algo que você não consegue ver normalmente, eu considero uma falha.