# Bug na fila de análises de primeiras publicações

Tags: bug, filas-de-análise

Notei no menu que haviam posts na fila de análises de **primeiras publicações**. Quando cliquei, me deparei com uma [publicação do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/166020), porém só soube que era dele depois que cliquei no [link da resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/284749/escrever-software-em-1%C2%AA-ou-3%C2%AA-pessoa/284754#284754) e pra minha surpresa foi uma resposta publicada há um tempo. Até então havia um avatar sem nome.

**O que ocorreu aqui?**

Tirei um print da tela de como ela surgiu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não se trata daqueles testes automáticos para ver se você está prestando atenção?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, será? Havia me esquecido totalmente destes testes... Aliás, nunca aconteceu comigo.

Comment: [Acho que é sim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5186/pergunta-excluída-aparecendo-nos-testes-da-fila-de-análise). O sistema me pegou, poxa vida.